# Is there Vertical Sharding in postgresql? (or other)

Tags: sql, postgresql, sharding

I used RDB in aws.

I inserted 5 billion rows in one table and need to add an index varchar type column.(To speed up the insert, I removed the index and proceeded.)

However, the following error is displayed and it takes too long.

```
ERROR:  could not write to file "base/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp707.0.sharedfileset/0.41": No space left on device
```

(I am using the `db.r6g.2xlarge` specification.)

So, I'm considering managing the table separately.

However, I want to divide table sharding by row pk id number (nextval('table_id'::regclass) ) instead of dividing by column.
And when querying with sql, I want to use it as one table.

It's like a vertical sharding(?) concept...!

Is this possible in postgresql?

As an additional question...
Is it possible to split a table that already has data on it by sharding?

Comment: Please clarify what "add an index varchar type column" means. Did you want to add a new varchar column named `index`? Or create an index on an existing column? Or something else. I also don't understand what "divide table sharding by row pk" is supposed to mean. Are you talking about [partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE)?

Comment: You clearly need more storage, that should be easy in a cloud solution.